# Problema de rotación en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

lo que sucede es que tengo un rectangulo que al presionar la tecla UP salta 360 grados, pero al llegar al suelo otro rectangulo debe colisionarlo, el asunto es que el empieza a empujarlo sin nisiquiera tocarlo, pero si no oprimo la tecla UP la colisión se hace correctamente. Les agradezco mucho pudieran ayudarme con respecto a esto, estoy aprendiendo sobre las rotaciones y como actualizar imagenes en la pantalla.

Este es el código

```
import pygame
NEGRO = (0, 0, 0)
BLANCO = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
RED = (255,0,0)
MORADO = (255,0,255)
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  
FPS = 60
pantalla = pygame.display.set_mode([800,600])
pygame.display.set_caption('')
personaje= pygame.Rect(50,470,50,50)
piso = pygame.Rect(0,520,800,20)
torre = pygame.Rect(300,440,100,80)
encimatorre = pygame.Rect(305,433,100,20)
estasaltando=False
rot = 0  
rot_speed = 4
juego =True
veltorre=1
velxperso=1
salto=20
image_orig = pygame.Surface((50 , 50))  
# for making transparent background while rotating an image  
image_orig.set_colorkey(NEGRO)  
# fill the rectangle / surface with green color  
image_orig.fill(YELLOW)  
# creating a copy of orignal image for smooth rotation  
image = image_orig.copy()  
image.set_colorkey(NEGRO)  
# define rect for placing the rectangle at the desired position  
rect = image.get_rect()  
rect.center = (50,470)  


while juego:
    
    clock.tick(FPS) 
    pantalla.fill(NEGRO)
    

    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        
        
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
            juego=False
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                 estasaltando=True
                 if rect.colliderect(torre) and estasaltando==True:
                    estasaltando= False
    
        
    if estasaltando:
        if salto >= -20 :
            old_center = rect.center  
            rot = (rot - rot_speed) % -360
            new_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image_orig, rot)
            rect = new_image.get_rect()
            rect.center = old_center
            rect.y -= salto
            salto -=1
            pantalla.blit(new_image , rect)
            #pygame.display.update()
            
            
            
            
            
            
    
                    
                    
                    
                    
            
            
            
            if rect.colliderect(encimatorre):
                         
               rect.bottom=torre.top
               salto =20
               estasaltando = False
               
                
                            
        else:
        
            salto = 20
            
            estasaltando = False
                    
    
         
    
                    
        
    if rect.colliderect(torre):
        rect.x -=2
        
         
    torre.x -=veltorre
    encimatorre.x-=veltorre
    
    if torre.x==-100:
        torre.x=700
        encimatorre.x=705
    
   
    
    pygame.draw.rect(pantalla,RED,torre)
    if not rect.colliderect(encimatorre) and estasaltando == False:
       
       
       
       rect.y += 40
       
       if rect.colliderect(piso):
        rect.y = 470
    if estasaltando== False :
        pantalla.blit(image_orig , rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(pantalla,RED,encimatorre)
  #  pygame.draw.rect(pantalla,YELLOW,personaje)
    pygame.draw.rect(pantalla,BLANCO,piso)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    
        
        
    
        
        
    
    
pygame.quit()
```

Este es el pantallazo de la prueba que estoy realizando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aqui se puede apreciar el rectangulo empuja al otro rectangulo sin ni siquiera tocarlo

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido, no creo que alguien pueda ayudarte, dado que no explicas la mecánica básica del juego, no puedo decir mucho, solo que tengas el cuenta que rotar 360°, es igual a no rotar, (a no ser que sea una animación), sería aconsejable que edites tu pregunta, y expliques bien que se supone que debe hacer tu código, y que es lo que hace.

Comment: @MarcePuente No estoy de acuerdo con tu comentario. El codigo funciona perfecto y es corto. Incluso pude reproducir el error, además de explicar el comportamiento no esperado y hasta poner captura.  Y aunque no esté bien formateado, es una pregunta de calidad. Lo unico que estoy de acuerdo, es que aunque queda implicito cual es el comportamiento esperado, es mejor aclararlo explicitamente.

Comment: @DanteS. podrías explicarme bajo que condiciones un cubo empuja al otro, quién mueve al que empuja, el jugador?, el bot?, yo nunca mencioné falta de calidad, no pongas en mi boca, cosas que no dije.

Comment: Me disculpo, tenés razón. Pero lo que disparó mi comentario fue: "y que es lo que hace", lo cual ya está explicado. Si puedo responder, pero a base de suposiciones. En eso estoy de acuerdo con vos. Nuevamente, perdón la ofensa.

Answer (score 0):

##### Bounding Rect

Cuando haces surface.get_rect() y lo posicionas, obtenés el rectangulo que contiene todos los pixeles de la superficie. Esto suele ser llamado en inglés "bounding rect".
Bajo esta logica, debería devolverte el rectangulo rotado que contiene todos los pixeles.
Pero hay un tema, **los pixeles completamente transparentes, siguen siendo pixeles**. Piensalo como si un pixel transparente, fuera también un color.

Entonces, el bounding rect no puede ser rotado, si no, no tendría todos los pixeles.

A continuación, dejaré un programa que muestra el cambio del "bounding rect" conforme se realiza una rotación automatica.

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def get_player1_mask():
    return player1.get_rect()

def get_player2_mask():
    return pygame.mask.from_surface(player2)

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y):
        super().__init__()

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.oimage = pygame.surface.Surface((40, 40)).convert_alpha()
        self.oimage.fill(color)

        self.image = self.oimage.copy()

        self.angle = 0

    @property
    def angle(self):
        return self._angle
    
    @angle.setter
    def angle(self, angle):
        self._angle = angle
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.oimage, angle)

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

class Player1(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__((255, 255, 255), 100, 100)

    def update(self):
        self.angle += 1

    def draw(self):
        super().draw()

        rect = self.image.get_rect()
        rect.x = self.x
        rect.y = self.y

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), rect, width=1)

pygame.init()
 
fps = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

player1 = Player1()

# Game loop.
while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # Update.

    player1.update()
  
    # Draw.
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    player1.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
    fpsClock.tick(fps)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto, explica el hecho de que justo cuando el rectangulo salte, la colisión no sea como se espera.

##### La opción más sencilla, mascaras

Pygame nos ofrece una funcionalidad muy buena cuando nuestra area de colisión no es un rectangulo: mascaras (pygame.mask.Mask).

¿Como funcionan? Las mascaras, en lugar de usar poligonos, guarda que pixeles deben considerarse para la colisión. Digamos que las mascaras son como las surfaces, pero en lugar de colores, tienen 0 y 1. Si el "pixel" es 0 o falso, significa que no se debe considerar para la colisión. Si es 1 o verdadero, entonces se considera parte del area de colisión.

No necesitas trabajar esto a fondo, ya que pygame hace el trabajo dificil por vos.

No puedo darte un tutorial de como usarlas ya que si no la respuesta sería demasiado extensa. Pero seguramente, encuentres algo en internet y también tenés [la documentación](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) a mano.

##### Otra forma que siento más conveniente (complicado si usas pygame)

Las mascaras pueden ocupar mucha memoria debido al uso de esos "pixeles", pero a la fecha de esta respuesta, un modulo de juegos llamado [arcade](https://api.arcade.academy/en/latest/), el cual recomiendo en especial a los novatos por que hace mucho del trabajo dificil, usa poligonos que se acercan a la forma de la imagen, un intermedio entre el bounding rect y la mascara. Sin embargo, pygame no ofrece una forma automatica. Por lo que si vas a avanzar con pygame, mejor usar mascaras.